# Unable to bind DataGridTemplateColumn ComboBox editing template

Tags: wpf, templates, datagrid, combobox

Following is my DataGrid XAML :

```
 <DataGrid Visibility="Visible" Margin="20" ItemContainerStyle="{x:Null}" OverridesDefaultStyle="False" CellStyle="{x:Null}" Style="{x:Null}" RowStyle="{x:Null}" ColumnHeaderStyle="{x:Null}" Foreground="Black" CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MovieList}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay}" CanUserResize="True" MaxWidth="450" CanUserSort="True" Header="Title" Width="200" />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="130" Header="Type">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Type}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GenreList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

The cell editing template has a ComboBox which is bound to an observable collection 'GenreList'. This collection is initialized in the ViewModel. What could be the reason for the ComboBox not getting populated ?

Comment: Is GenreList in the ViewModel for the `DataGrid` or in the ViewModel for the `DataGridRow`? Just a guess but try `ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.GenreList}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not getting to your ViewModel. You need to travel up to the source - a visual element that is bound to your ViewModel.  For example, if it is all the way up on the view, lets assume it's of type UserControl, the following will work:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=GenreList}".... />
```

Another way, if you want to make sure you pick of the binding from correct element, not base of a type, give the element that bounds to your ViewModel a name (I'll use the same UserControl)

```
<UserControl x:Name="me".../>

   <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=me, Path=DataContext.GenreList}".... />
```

Comment: It will work if it's a property of the `UserControl`, otherwise if it's in the `DataContext` you'll need `DataContext.GenreList`